# multinomial Naive Bayes classifier python

Tags: python

I’m using multinomial Naive Bayes classifier for text classification consist of (5 classes and 1764 sentences of training data)
As is the code in the link(https://chatbotslife.com/text-classification-using-algorithms-e4d50dcba45)
When classifying some data in the classifier,, it changes every run and returns different label every time,, How to fix the label with the same results
Thank you …

Comment: Set the seed for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a change in your classification. As there are no random initialisations. The similarity between sentences should always be the same. Could you also share your code, so I can have a look.

Comment: blooded
48●44 bronze badges
yes, this is happening ..when test exact word in data set and the word has more than class,, such as {word1, label A1, B2} classify(word1) give A1, the second run gives B2 and so on. I used the same code in the link but the different dataset thank you very much